# A map that sometimes run fast, and sometimes slow

Tags: oracle, informatica

I built up a map containing this logic:

```
SOURCES -> SORTER -> AGG(FIRST BY GROUP) -> 2 LOOKUPS -> FILTER -> TARGET
```

Now, when I manually run the query generated by the sources, adding the 2 lookups with a `LEFT JOIN` and sorting, the query takes about 30 seconds.

I ran the same map in my `DEV` environment  to try to debug it , but suddenly it ran in 2 minutes(connected to the same connection as in the `PRODUCTION` , and the map is trunc/insert)

I looked up the history of this session, and its running time is between 6 minutes up to hour+ , with the same amount of data every day!

I've tried adding statistics/increasing the commit interval but nothing seems to help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: usually when I see dramatic differences in query runtimes between 2 instances, my first thought is the faster instance (dev in this case) has many blocks already in buffer cache

Comment: Already solved, you can see in the last comment on Koushik answer @tbone. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, the query from source (with lookups) return you data within 30 seconds doesn't mean you will get all data by 30 second. The SQL client tool shows only first 50 to 500 records. Extracting complete data set may need more time. 
Now, i don't see many reasons for slowness. Here are my thoughts -

- Did you find any pattern of slowness? Like during month end or month start etc.? All i can see is mainly source and lookup (if table) data may be reason of slowness. See, when a table size varies rapidly or table is not analyzed or table undergoes lot of delete/load operation, its cost varies and SQL becomes slower. Make sure stats are gathered periodically for lookup and source tables.
- May be some other operations (that is running in parallel to your map) is eating up all your resources so its taking 1 hour to complete the map.
- how much data it processes? In thousands, millions or billions? Depending on that you can re-arrange map like this source > source qual> lookup > filter  > sorter + aggregator > target to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes it does take 60 seconds to fetch the entire data - the sources are around 6MIL records, but with the join and conditions the source selects 300k. The two looks ups are 2MIL and 10MIL , I did not recognize any pattern which is the weird part! The target is new, and most of the sources are not used any where else, so nothing parallel as much as I'm aware of. I can't change the order of the map since I first need to use AGG to get the first record, and do the rest with it. I'm trying to replace LOOKUP with JOINERs, lets see what happens.

Comment: Analyze session log, if source read is taking time then think about gathering statistics regularly as well. You can ask DBA to do this. They should have automated script for this. You can use Database functions like FIRST_VALUE or something like that to pickup first value instead of aggregator.  If you can, please post complete session log for 1hr run.

Comment: If the source tables can have different data volumes at different times, as is common with staging tables, it's possible that statistics were gathered at a time when the data volumes were not representative of when your query ran. A good resolution to this is to delete statistics entirely (and lock the table stats), and let dynamic sampling gather them at query time. This might only be suitable if the same source tables are not being used for transactional queries also.

Comment: Well, it was the look up that was slowing down the process, probably something with the cache. I don't know why it worked fast on the develop environment but joiner fixed the issue. Thanks anyway @davidaldridge